# Rollback the entire package in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

I created 3 different packages in SSIS to extract the required data from the DB. Still those 3 packages are yet to be deployed. So, I want to know is there a way say for example if i run the packages in the sequence package1, package2 and package3. Suddenly, if the package2 get some error and stopped in the middle then i want to rollback all the changes made till the error occurred in package2.

Kindly, let me know as how i can do that? whether i need to deploy the package and then do some procedure to rollback or before even deploying the package can i do some procedure to rollback the change till the error.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,

Mohan

Answer (score -1):

We know we have DTEXEC.EXE Command Line Utility to run the SSIS package. Try if we can use this command for all three packages within transaction using BEGIN TRAN, END.

Please note this will work only when TRANSACTIONs are set to SUPPORTED in all your SSIS packages.

Comment: People who have down voted, please mention the reason as well! It might not be a solution. But definitely gives an idea to try.